# Get the last object in an array inside an array :O

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Let's say  have an ArrayList inside another ArrayList whitch contains Strings.

```
private List<ArrayList<String>> strings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

After adding some arrays and strings i want to get the last string in the last array, how do I do?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Couldn't you find that by reading the javadoc of List?

Comment: Note that your code doesn't demonstrate any arrays - only lists.

Comment: Damn, I did try simular things, to tired I guess :/, sorry for posting a bad post!

Comment: @Daniel: next time, post what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can use:

```
ArrayList<String> lastList = strings.get(strings.size() - 1);
String lastString = lastList.get(lastList.size() - 1);
```

Or with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) (or your own `getLast` method, which would be easy to write...):

```
String lastString = Iterables.last(Iterables.last(strings));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> lastInnerList = strings.get(strings.size() - 1);
String lastString = lastInnerList.get(lastInnerList.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String lastElement = strings.get(strings.size()-1).get(strings.get(strings.size()-1).size()-1);
```

Comment: You've demonstrated why it's a good idea to separate this out into two statements - your `get` call should be `.get(strings.get(strings.size()-1).size()-1)`

Comment: Unless you've got something like Guava, anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int outerListSize = strings.size();
ArrayList<String> lastInnerList = strings.get(outerListSize - 1);
int lastInnerListSize = lastInnerList.size();
String str = lastInnerList.get(lastInnerListSize - 1);
```